# Flutter app does not return to the app post user authentication from Google Oauth

Tags: flutter, api, oauth, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have created a flutter app which adds calendar events to user's google calendar using the google Calendar API. The app is doing the job but I have the following problem.

The app has `initializeCalendarApi();` function(code attached below) in the `initState()` function which authenticates the user using Google Oauth. This is done by redirecting the user to user's browser where they select their ***Google account*** and click ***Allow*** to allow app to access their calendar. The problem is, once the authentication is done, the browser window is not closed automatically and the user has to close the browser app and shift to the flutter app manually which is bad for a production app.

How do I resolve this to make sure the user automatically gets back to the flutter app after clicking *Allow*.

```
  Future<void> initializeCalendarApi() async {
    var _clientID = new ClientId(Secret.getId(), "");
    const _scopes = const [calendar.CalendarApi.calendarScope];
    await clientViaUserConsent(_clientID, _scopes, prompt)
        .then((AuthClient client) async {
      CalendarClient.calendar = calendar.CalendarApi(client);
    });
  }
```

**Image shows the final Page Obtained in browser after Oauth has been completed. I want to return my flutter app after successful authentication rather than this window opened in browser.**

[image: Image shows the final Page Obtained in browser after Oauth has been completed.]